# Reg Expression validation for digits after decimal must be either zero or >= 1/tenth

Tags: regex, validation

I need a regular expression if values entered are great than zero, the 2 digits after the decimal are either zeros, or greater than or equal .10 (1/tenth)

For example: 0.00 or 0.10 or 35.00 or 35.95 , but not 0.06 or 35.07

The reason is to make sure if a value is entered the entered values not less than 1/tenth, and if no value then allow 0.00

Sorry I forgot to indicate that it can also take an integer, or 1 decimal place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are u looking for something like this?

```
 ^\d+[.](([1-9]\d)|(00))$
```

> break down
> ^ = start of the line
> \d+ = 1 or more digits
>  [.] = a dot (without the brackets its meaning can be any character)
>  ([1-9]\d) = one time 1 till 9 and after that a digit
> |(00)  = or 2 zeros
> $ = end of the line (no other character afterwards

for a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bD0eJ4/2) check this link.

edit:

```
^\d+(\.([1-9]\d?|00?))?$
```

the `?` means 1 times or zero times so this way u get it at

> breakdown on the edited part
>  \d? = one or zero digits
>  00? = 1 or 2 zeros
>  (.([1-9]\d?|00?))? = the part withing the brackets one or zero times

this way u get it for integers and doubles with the first digit 1 or higher if there are 2 digits and if there is only one digit it will pick it always [demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/bD0eJ4/3)

Comment: That is great! Can it be modified so if an integer or only one decimal is entered it will be valid also?